# CAGradientLayer shows totally translucent

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, calayer

I am trying to create two gradient layers, one at each side of a scroll view so as to show that there is content to scroll to.

The one on the left side works fine but the one on the right shows totally transparent. What am I missing?

[image: Xib]

[image: Reveal]

```
CAGradientLayer *l = [CAGradientLayer layer];
l.frame = self.leftBlur.frame;
l.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor, nil];
l.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.5f);
l.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.5f);
self.leftBlur.layer.mask = l;

self.leftBlur.hidden = YES;

CAGradientLayer *r = [CAGradientLayer layer];
r.frame = self.rightBlur.frame;
r.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, nil];
r.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.5f);
r.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.5f);
self.rightBlur.layer.mask = r;
```

Debug output:

```
(lldb) po r
<CAGradientLayer:0x170ba6d0; position = CGPoint (305 62.5); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 30 125); allowsGroupOpacity = YES; endPoint = CGPoint (1 0.5); startPoint = CGPoint (0 0.5); colors = (
    "<CGColor 0x15e590e0> [<CGColorSpace 0x15e34b50> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceGray)] ( 1 1 )",
    "<CGColor 0x17012ed0> [<CGColorSpace 0x15d15310> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB)] ( 1 0 0 1 )"
)>
(lldb) po self.rightBlur
<UIImageView: 0x171377d0; frame = (290 0; 30 125); autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17137860>>
(lldb) po l
<CAGradientLayer:0x170b9f00; position = CGPoint (15 62.5); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 30 125); allowsGroupOpacity = YES; endPoint = CGPoint (1 0.5); startPoint = CGPoint (0 0.5); colors = (
    "<CGColor 0x15e590e0> [<CGColorSpace 0x15e34b50> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceGray)] ( 1 1 )",
    "<CGColor 0x15d39320> [<CGColorSpace 0x15e34b50> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceGray)] ( 0 0 )"
)>
(lldb) po self.leftBlur
<UIImageView: 0x17136fc0; frame = (0 0; 30 125); hidden = YES; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17137050>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the gradient layer's frame to be equal to the `rightBlur`'s frame. This will offset the layer within `rightBlur`. You should set it to its bounds:

```
r.frame = self.rightBlur.bounds;
```

For the left side this worked because its origin is (0,0)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is most likely due to the colors being from different color spaces. Notice when you do `po r`, the colors are not in the same color space - one is from RGB and the other is from Gray.

I would suggest that instead of using the `[UIColor clearColor]`, you use `[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0]`. Use with `[UIColor whiteColor]` for the other color will result in both colors being in the same color space.

Edit: Actually the problem is probably the `frame` issue pointed out by "diederikh".

Comment: My layer was getting an initial black color instead of clear color and I did not understand why. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone comes over this question, but it still doesn't work:

Remember to make the array of colors with CGColor objects instead of UIColor.

I spent 30 minutes wondering why my gradient didn't work.

Hope this helps someone.